# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors Order

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, code-review

Say I have a list of eigenvalues and eigenvectors produced from a matrix $M$ using the command `{eig1,eig2}=Eigensystem[M]`, which will return the eigenvalues with respective eigenvectors of $M$.

I want to now produce a new list `list1` which will output a list of eigenvalues and the $L^{\infty}$ norms of the respective eigenvectors. How could this be done?

I previously defined `Eig1[m_]:=Eigenvalues[m]` and `Eig2[m_]:=Eigenvectors[m]`, then used:

`EigIf[m_]:=Map[Max[#]&,Eig2[m]]`

To then obtain the table with `{Eig1[m_],EigIf[m_]}`. However, I'm not sure if the order in which the eigenvectors are returned with `Eigenvectors[m]` is respective to the order given by `Eigenvalues[m]` (so the first eigenvalue in the latter corresponds to the first eigenvector in `Eigenvectors[m]`). Can something similar be done with `Eigensystem[m]`?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I can't quite figure out this question.  Jens voted to close this as a duplicate (see link above) but you appear to already be aware of the use of `Eigensystem`.  Can you restate the problem, focusing on why you are unable to apply `Eigensystem` as desired?

Comment: As noted, use `Eigensystem`. It is not guaranteed that orders of values and vectors, computed separately, will correspond whereas with `Eigensystem` they do.

Answer (score 2):

A neater answer just uses `Eigensystem`:

```
MapAt[Max, Eigensystem[m], {2, All}] // Transpose
```

For input `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`, this returns `{{1/2 (5 + Sqrt[33]), 1}, {1/2 (5 - Sqrt[33]), 1}}`.